# Eliminar elementos duplicados de un array multidemensional con PHP

Tags: php, php7

Tengo el siguiente array multidemensional y su estructura es la siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-05
            [pago] => 1
            [total] => 2500
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-05
            [pago] => 2
            [total] => 500
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-06
            [pago] => 1
            [total] => 3500
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-06
            [pago] => 1
            [total] => 600
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-07
            [pago] => 1
            [total] => 1500
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-08
            [pago] => 1
            [total] => 5250
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-08
            [pago] => 2
            [total] => 2500
        )

)
```

Lo que necesito es crear otro array pero sin duplicar las fechas, entonces yo espero algo asi:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-05
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-06
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-07
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-08
        )

)
```

Al momento tengo esto:

```
function eliminarDuplicados($array)
{   
    $fechasSinDuplicadar = array_unique(array_column($array, "fecha"));
    $fechas = array();
    
    array_walk($fechasSinDuplicadar, function($v) use (&$fechas){
        array_push($fechas, array("fecha" => $v));
    });
    
    return $fechas;
}
```

Ese código que muestro si me resuelve el problema pero habrá alguna otra forma de realizar esto usando funciones que ya estan definidas en **PHP** que me optimize más el proceso??

Comment: ¿Sólo necesitas las fechas, sin recoger ni hacer nada con `pago` y `total`?

Comment: @A.Cedano asi es, solo requiero las fechas pero sin que se dupliquen

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente puedes combinar [`array_unique()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php) con [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-column.php), tal y como ya lo tienes al inicio de tu función. Todo lo demás sobra.

Suponiendo que tu array se llama `$datos`, sería algo así:

```
$fechas = array_unique(array_column($datos, 'fecha'));
var_dump($fechas);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "2024-01-05"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "2024-01-06"
}
```

Si lo quieres escribir en una función, podrías hacer algo como:

```
function eliminarDuplicados($array,$keyName)
{  
    #Verificamos primero que $keyName existe en el array
    if(array_column($array, $keyName)) 
    {
        $tmp=array_unique(array_column($array, $keyName));
        $fechas=[];
        foreach ($tmp as $v) {
            $fechas[][$keyName]=$v;
        }
        return $fechas;
    }
    return false;
}
```

La función devolverá los datos correctos, si el segundo parámetro existe como clave del array:

```
var_dump(eliminarDuplicados($datos,'fecha'));
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-05
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [fecha] => 2024-01-06
        )

)
```

En caso contrario, devolverá `false`:

```
var_dump(eliminarDuplicados($datos,'fake'));
```

**Salida:**

```
bool(false)
```

Comment: Tu propuesta es efectiva pero sucede que se necesita que los indices sean de tipo string asi como lo muestro en el ejmplo y en tu propuesta los indices son de tipo numérico.

Comment: @JorgeAlonso revisa la función modificada. He agregado un `foreach` para crear el array final con una clave `fecha` en cada caso. Dicho eso, ten en cuenta que todos los arrays tienen un índice numérico siempre, que corresponde a la posición de cada elemento en ese array. Desde un punto de vista práctico, poner una clave repetida en un array es algo redundante. En cualquier uso, sabiendo que ese dato es fijo, lo puedes usar como tal, definiéndolo por ejemplo en una cadena.